# Can the order of min max be exchanged in the following problem with integer variable?

Tags: optimization, game-theory

I have a min-max problem:
$$
\min_x\{\max\{f_1(x),f_2(x)\}\}
$$

Can this min-max be solved (or somehome equivalent to):
$$
\max\{\min_xf_1(x),\min_xf_2(x)\}
$$

when both $f_1(\cdot)$ and $f_2(\cdot)$ are convex?

My initial thought is to rewrite the original problem by introducing binary variable $a$:
$$
\min_x\max_{a\in Z}af_1(x) + (1-a)f_2(x)
$$

I know that if $a\in[0,1]$, then we can use Von Neumann's Minimax theorem. However, I am not sure there is a version of Von Neumann's that can be applied to integer variable or will the relaxation from $a\in\{0,1\}$ to $a\in[0,1]$ result in the same solution to the original problem.

Any suggestions or references are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two forms are not equivalent. Take $f_1(x):=(x-1)^2$ and $f_2(x):=(x+1)^2$. Each function is convex, and you can check that
$$\min_x\{\max\{f_1(x),f_2(x)\}\} = 1,$$
with the minimum occurring at $x=0$, while $\min_x f_1(x) =0$, occurring at $x=1$, and $\min_x f_2(x)=0$, occurring at $x=-1$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! May I ask a following up question? When dealing with the inner maximization on binary variable a, can we treat both $f_1$ and $f_2$ as constant, so that we have a linear function on a. In this case, $a\in\{0,1\}$ can be relaxed into [0,1] as the maxima is at the boundary if $f_1\neq f_2$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, in the inner maximization on $a$, the value of $x$ is held constant.